# What is the equivalent of $(which docker) for windows?

Tags: docker, jenkins

For context:

```
docker run -p 81:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name myjenkins --privileged -v %cd%/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker jenkins/jenkins
```

What is $(which docker) doing here?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? There's a lot more that won't work on Windows with this line than the last part

Comment: It all works on windows, but I haven't added that last bit because i know it will break. I'm tyring to enable running docker-compose in my jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Are you sure? All other paths look like Unix paths, which will never work on Windows

Comment: it does work. I'm using cmder which has bash ability.

Answer (score 1):

Similar command of 'which' for Windows should be 'where'.

```
-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker
```

Above argument mount host docker binary to guest. 
Unless you have same OS in host and guest, binary will be incompatible, by the way.

Comment: if i run ls -l $(which docker) in linux what does it do?

Comment: @SteveTomlin it returns the path (without -l) to docker binary or script like this - /usr/local/bin/docker, (ls -l is just more information like permission, user:group timestamp, etc...)

Comment: Brilliant. This is what I'm looking for. So the question is where is the equivalant location of /usr/local/bin/docker on a windows 10 machine that is running docker community edition?

Comment: Is it something like this: C:\Users\[me]\.docker\machine\machines\default ?

Comment: yeah, something like that. but take a look the contents of that file, if that path is shortcut or some kind of script, it might not work in guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the correct path should be but this is what I have tried.

```
-v "C:\Users\[me]\.docker\machine\machines\default"
```

in context of running jenkins in order to get docker-compose to work.
Doesn't break but doesn't enable docker-compose to be found in jenkins pipeline. Despite having docker-compose plugin installed.

```
docker run -p 81:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name myjenkins --privileged -v %cd%/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v "C:\Users\[me]\.docker\machine\machines\default":/usr/bin/docker jenkins/jenkins
```